# How to resolve AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i found this wicked piece of code that im going to try and use for a project to scrape song data off spotify- only thing is the piece of code is broken and could use a little bit of love. Any ideas as to why i receive the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'' for line 36 ? here is my code;

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
from time import sleep
from datetime import date, timedelta

#create empty arrays for data we're collecting
dates=[]
url_list=[]
final = []

#map site

url = "https://spotifycharts.com/regional/au/weekly"
start_date= date(2016, 12, 29)
end_date= date(2020, 12, 24)

delta= end_date-start_date

for i in range(delta.days+1):
    day = start_date+timedelta(days=i)
    day_string= day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    dates.append(day_string)

def add_url():
    for date in dates:
        c_string = url+date
        url_list.append(c_string)

add_url()

#function for going through each row in each url and finding relevant song info

def song_scrape(x):
    pg = x
    for tr in songs.find("tbody").findAll("tr"):
        artist= tr.find("td", {"class": "chart-table-track"}).find("span").text
        artist= artist.replace("by ","").strip()
  
        title= tr.find("td", {"class": "chart-table-track"}).find("strong").text
 
        songid= tr.find("td", {"class": "chart-table-image"}).find("a").get("href")
        songid= songid.split("track/")[1]
    
        url_date= x.split("daily/")[1]
        
        final.append([title, artist, songid, url_date])
    
#loop through urls to create array of all of our song info

for u in url_list:
    read_pg= requests.get(u)
    sleep(2)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(read_pg.text, "html.parser")
    songs= soup.find("table", {"class":"chart-table"})
    song_scrape(u)
 
#convert to data frame with pandas for easier data manipulation

final_df = pd.DataFrame(final, columns= ["Title", "Artist", "Song ID", "Chart Date"])

#write to csv

with open('spmooddata.csv', 'w') as f:
        final_df.to_csv(f, header= True, index=False)
```

Comment: Please also add the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The function `song_scrape` uses the external `songs` param, which is `None` for some cases, e.g. an invalid url, or any page that doesn't contain the specific table being search for (a table of class chart-table).
So for example, you've got a url (https://spotifycharts.com/regional/au/weekly2016-12-29) with a page-not-found result, and so the line that searches for a table returns `None`. Which indeed has no `find` attribute...
In fact, *all* of your urls are invalid! So what you *really* need to do is to fix your url list.

---

Let's go deeper:
It seems that spotify has changed the url format, to now use a "from-date--to-date" structure. If you fix-up the url-building part of your code that's a first step to setting things back on track.  So for starters -

```
start_date = date(2021, 1, 8)
end_date = date(2021, 6, 30)

num_of_dates = (end_date - start_date).days // 7

for i in range(num_of_dates):
    start_day = start_date + timedelta(days=i * 7)
    start_day_string = start_day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    end_day = start_date + timedelta(days=(i + 1) * 7)
    end_day_string = end_day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    dates.append('--'.join([start_day_string, end_day_string]))
```

... gives valid urls!

But at this point, it seems that there're some security measures installed, because instead of loading the actual page, I'm being referred to a captcha page. But that's a whole different question :-)

---

Note: Before scraping web pages, it's worth looking at the robots.txt file.
In this case, the file https://spotifycharts.com/robots.txt shows -

> User-agent: *
> Disallow:

So one shouldn't have a problem crawling spotify. For overcoming captchas, try looking at the [python-anticaptch package](https://pypi.org/project/python-anticaptcha/)